# Windows10 で Ctrl + B などのショートカットに別のキーを割り当てたい

Tags: windows

Windows 10 で以下の操作を実現したいです。

- Ctrlキーを押しながらBキーを押すと、BackSpaceキーを押したことにしたい
- Ctrlキーを押しながらNキーを押すと、Altキーを押しながら↑キーを押したことにしたい

Windowsの標準機能で実現できますか？ それともバッチファイルやソフトウェアが必要ですか？
また、どうやって調べたらよいですか？ プログラムとしては何言語になるのですか？

Comment: たぶん「ChangeKey」のほうがわかりやすいと思います。

Comment: 質問内容を一部変更しました。

Comment: これらは OS 全体で有効になること (例えばメモ帳等も含めて) を期待していますか？ Ctrl + N は「新規作成」に割り当てられていることが多いですし、割り当てるキーバインドもいまいちどのような動作になるのかが分かりません。何か特定のアプリを想定しているようであれば、それらの情報も含めておいたほうが回答が付きやすいかもしれません。

Comment: 特定アプリではなく OS 全体で有効になることを期待しています。 Ctrl + N が「新規作成」に割り当てられていることは知らなかったので、Ctrl + Ｍでもよいです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PowerToys の Keyboard Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/powertoys/keyboard-manager) でできると思います。Remap shortcutsでこのように指定できます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]