# Windows10の「Ctrl」か「Alt」を使用したホットキーで、割り当てられていない組合せの一覧を知りたい

Tags: windows-10

「Ctrl」と「任意の一つのキー」あるいは「Alt」と「任意の一つのキー」を使用して、キー割り当て変更を行いたいのですが、なるべく既存の割り当てと重複させたくありません。

そこで、「Ctrl」か「Alt」を使用したホットキーで、割り当てられていない組合せの一覧を知りたいのですが、どこかに一覧表のようなものはありませんか？

Comment: [以前も似たようなコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/88368/windows10-%e3%81%a7-ctrl-b-%e3%81%aa%e3%81%a9%e3%81%ae%e3%82%b7%e3%83%a7%e3%83%bc%e3%83%88%e3%82%ab%e3%83%83%e3%83%88%e3%81%ab%e5%88%a5%e3%81%ae%e3%82%ad%e3%83%bc%e3%82%92%e5%89%b2%e3%82%8a%e5%bd%93%e3%81%a6%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84#comment100199_88368) をしましたが、対象を明確にしましょう。特定のアプリのみに対してなのか、Windows の OS 自体に対してなのかによっても変わってくると思います。

Comment: Windows の OS 自体に対してです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

キーボードショートカット（アクセラレータ）は（標準的なものを除き）プログラムの作者が任意に決めていいものなので「すべてのプログラムで一切使われていない」一覧表というものは無いです。

標準的な [ショートカットキー一覧](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%82%AB%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7) だとこんなものかも（むしろそのリンク先のほうが有用かも）

Emacs とかだと Windows / MacOS の標準などガン無視して独自の道を突っ走っていますし、あなたのプログラムによって勝手に再マップされてしまうと全世界の Emacs/に限らず ユーザーが泣いちゃいます。